Getting started developing a marketplace
I'm an experienced software developer coming from the front end. I've started learning Rust and Anchor, but I feel the regular paths don't necessarily lead me where I need, at least not quickly and accurately. I believe in learning what's needed to get the work done first and then expand.
I understand the basics of Rust and understand how to create and test an Anchor program, which increments, decrements and updates a value, but that's about it.
I lack basic understanding on how buying and selling tokens/items work on the network. Not necessarily NFTs. From that point I need to understand what I need to learn and where to learn it. Of course it could be existing free tutorials, or paid Udemy courses.
Any help appreciated.

From my knowledge Auction house program was primary built to enable devs build mnarketplaces
From their docs

AuctionHouse is a protocol for marketplaces to implement a decentralized sales contract. It is simple, fast and very cheap.

ref: https://docs.rs/mpl-auction-house/latest/mpl_auction_house/
But the above only works with the old token metadata program and you might need to support various standards.
You can check out our own implementation of an NFT marketplace using Metaplex core here https://github.com/SoundWorkLabs/marketplace-contracts
or check this out using the Metaplex Metadata program
https://github.com/ASCorreia/anchor-marketplace/tree/main/programs/anchor-marketplace

Thanks. I think this is a bit above my basic understanding. I don't even know the flow of buying and selling. I'm guessing it's some sort of escrow account that awaits for both the token and Solana until it exchanges them and then shuts down? Even if this is the gist, I need to understand to the implementation level.

that's correct. I'd say first interact with the popular marketplaces, Magic Eden, Tensor to get a feel of how they work

Is there a way to interact with them on DevNet for training purposes?

Soundwork is currently on devnet. Tensor isn't and I haven't tried magic eden
